# Combinatorial explosion of class hierarchy

Tags: oop, inheritance, design-patterns

I have a class hierarchies that differ only in some attributes and i want to create classes that are a combination of class hierarchies (like uml picture) which can lead to exploded hierarchy.
is there any solution to this design? it is like decorator pattern but on attributes not on behavior. Is it possible to use decorator as an alternative to inheritance[image]

Comment: You can use Interfaces+Composition+Delegation instead of extends.  Wikipedia's page on Composition over inheritance has some good examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance  But it kindof depends on what language you're talking about.  Some languages have more elegant solutions to solving this problem (Like Go's automatic delegation to composed objects, or Scala's Traits, or Ruby's Mixins, etc).

Comment: Why not just put all the fields in one data structure and let clients read what they need? Without behavior there is no polymorphism, so no need for inheritance or composition.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.
What you need to do is invert the dependency of this hierarchy. In a language that supports Interfaces(like c#), you can create those structures and combine them to provide this behavior.

The "**Combination**" will be decorated by the **Base class** which inherits **Combination Class** and implements **ChildClass1(Interface)** and **ChildClass2(Interface)** for instance. Considering **Base class** as a **Decorator**. Check the Decorator Pattern in C# [Here](https://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern).

Another option is not using the Decorator at all, having **Base Class**, **ChidClass1**, **2** and **3** being **Interfaces**.